# Ms word VBA: include text file line into an array

Tags: vba, ms-word

Such I have a text file that contain the below lines:

Line 1

Line2 etc

Line 3 etc

Now, I want to read the text file and include the all of line into an array like this:

LineList = Array("Line 1", "Line2 etc", "Line 3 etc")

How can I do this in ms word vba macro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a FileSystemObject to read line by line. Personally I'd use a Collection rather than an array so that I don't have to constantly use ReDim Preserve:

```
Sub S43490204()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fso
    Dim oCollection As New Collection

    filePath = "lines.txt"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1, False) '1 = ForReading

    On Error GoTo closeTarget

    Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
        oCollection.Add txtStream.ReadLine
    Loop

closeTarget:
    txtStream.Close

    'I'm not sure why you'd want an array instead of a collection
    Dim myArr() As String: myArr = GetStringArrayFromCollection(oCollection)

    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        Debug.Print " - " + myArr(i)
    Next i

End Sub

Function GetStringArrayFromCollection(oCollection As Collection) As String()
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim arr(0 To oCollection.Count - 1)

    For i = 1 To oCollection.Count
        arr(i - 1) = oCollection(i)
    Next i

    GetStringArrayFromCollection = arr

End Function
```